# NVME SSD not detected from Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: partitioning, ssd, fujitsu-siemens, m2

I recently build up my new pc and wanted to have an nvme ssd as boot drive but unfortunately its not supported.

I activated AHCI Mode instead of RAID in Bios and i even looked for Intel Rapid Technology but since i cannot turn that off anywhere, i guess my build does not support it. I tried several programs in linux that can show drives and patitions but no one showed anything.

I plugged that drive in correctly because there are 3 LEDs blinking when the pc is powered on

This is my stuff:

Fujitsu d3417-b11

Intel i3-6320

And [Intenso M.2 SSD top](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B077D1WYW3/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Can you help me fix that problem?

Comment: It looks like a M.2 SATA drive, not a M.2 NVMe drive. Do you also have a drive in a SATA port? Check your manual as normally one SATA port is disabled when using M.2 port. Have you updated UEFI firmware? My new Dell with RAID on just worked with Kubuntu 22.04. It used the Intel VMD driver which seems more for NVMe drives.